# dataframe merging + comparison with existence test

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am looking to perform the following task:

> Given 2 pandas DataFrames, each with one column but of different length, create a new DataFrame whose index is the union of the 2 other DataFrames and possesses two columns: one indicating whether DataFrame 1 contained a value for that particular index, and one indicating whether DataFrame 2 contained a value for that particular index.

I have the following example data:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=365, freq='D')
rng2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2016',periods=730, freq='D')
x1 = np.random.randn(365)
x2 = np.random.randn(730)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x1}, index=rng)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x2}, index=rng2)
```

I can obtain the union of the indices by doing:

```
idx = df1.index.union(df2.index)
```

Now, I would like to create a new DataFrame, `df3`, which has index of `idx` and 2 columns populated with zeroes and ones as per the above requirements.

I have explored using the `.isin()` functionality but from what I can tell that might require knowing a little bit too much about the DataFrames beforehand, while I would like to achieve this more flexibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *outer join* and a test for `notnull()` achieves the desired behavior.  With your example data it would look something like:

```
notnull = df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'x': 'x2'}), how='outer').notnull()
```

**Sample Data:**

```
rng1 = pd.date_range('1/2/2017', periods=4, freq='D')
rng2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=4, freq='D')
x = np.random.randn(4)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x}, index=rng1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x}, index=rng2)
```

**Test it:**

```
notnull = df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'x': 'x2'}), how='outer').notnull()
print(notnull)
```

**Output:**

```
                x     x2
2017-01-01  False   True
2017-01-02   True   True
2017-01-03   True   True
2017-01-04   True   True
2017-01-05   True  False
```

**Update from the Comments:**

If you want *actual* ones and zeros instead of `bool`,

```
ones_and_zeros= df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'x': 'x2'}), 
                                    how='outer').notnull().astype(np.uint8)
print(ones_and_zeros)
```

**Output:**

```
            x  x2
2017-01-01  0   1
2017-01-02  1   1
2017-01-03  1   1
2017-01-04  1   1
2017-01-05  1   0
```

Comment: Nice solution! I would also add convertion to `np.uint8`: `df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'x': 'x2'}), how='outer').notnull().astype(np.uint8)` so it'll produce ones and zeros